# Angular RxJS Jest Observables Completing on a Different Frame

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs, rxjs, observable

I am trying to use Jest in my Angular application to test RxJS Observables and am running into an issue using the TestScheduler.

My generic sample Jest test below where the `runMethodForService()` method calls `getArray()` on myService which is mocked to return an observable of an array.

```
let testScheduler: TestScheduler;

beforeEach(() => {
  testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
});

it('', () => {
  myServiceMock.getArray.mockReturnValueOnce(of([1,2,3]))
  component.runMethodForService();

  testScheduler.run(({expectObservable}) => {
    const expectedMarble = 'a|';
    const expectedArray = {a: mockArray};
    expectObservable(component.myObservable$).toBe(expectedMarble, expectedArray);
  });
});
```

My expected marble `'a|'` just emits one value and then completes. And the expected value is some array. But I am getting the below as my expected and actual results

| Expected | Actual |
| --- | --- |
| ``` [ { "frame": 0, "notification": { "kind": "N", "value": [ ... ] } }, { "frame": 1, <--- Error here "notification": { "kind": "C" } } ] ``` | ``` [ { "frame": 0, "notification": { "kind": "N", "value": [ ... ] } }, { "frame": 0, <--- Error here "notification": { "kind": "C" } } ] ``` |

It looks like the actual result is that the observable completes on the same frame as the value but the expectation is that it completes one frame after.

I tried wrapping my marble in parentheses `'(a|)'` like is shown in the docs but then the test times out after 5 seconds and cannot complete. Not sure if there is something missing that is causing the completion to be expected on the same frame as the value is emitted.

Comment: "Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that what you are observing is that `of([1,2,3])` is run synchronously thus terminating in the same frame.

So the matching marble should be `'(a|)'`

Comment: Right, which is what the Jest test shows as the actual result. But when I try wrapping the whole thing in one frame like that the test just times out. It was my understanding that the `done()` callback is not needed when using the TestScheduler like this, correct?

Comment: So I found a partial solution. I was experimenting with another test and found that if I add at least 1 more marble I can wrap everything in one frame. For example, `(ab|)` or `(#a|)`  both work. When I only use one marble like shown before `(a|)` (which is the expected case for what I am testing) it will always timeout the case.

It appears that this will not work when testing with only one marble like I need. Is it only possible to test this case then using a subscribe and assert pattern rather than the TestScheduler?